# How typesafety should be handled in gcloud functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using gcloud functions to handle some information in the realtime database. Is there a way to add some type safety to the params/body content of the request object?

For example:

```js
exports.createUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    email,
    nDevices,
    role,
    isAdmin,
    userLvl,
  } = req.query;

}
```

all of the variables are of type:

```
(property) Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>.query: QueryString.ParsedQs
```

How am I supposed to specify each type correctly?